# mysql query error matching data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm getting an error in sql

I have three tables

T1, t2, t3

in t1

```
id name
1  a
2  b
3  c
4  d
5  e
```

in t2

```
t1_id name
4     sac
2     sau
4     rah
4     seh
1     kaif
5     zah
6     aas
8     ram
```

in t3

```
t1_t2_id  name count lif_lin
1         Eve    2     no
2         sun    1     no
3         mon    0     no
4         tue    3     no
5         wed    1     no
6         thu    1     no
```

I want to count the how much t1_id element's exist in t1 respectively of id, t1_id in t1_t2_id

Mean  I have category id in t1 and the same category id in t2 table with t1_id and t3 t1_t2_id and i want to count the how many matches found in t2 with the same t1_t2_id

Comment: What is the error? What is your current sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I exactly understand what you are saying but try:

`SELECT count(a.id)
from t1 a
join t2 b on a.id = b.t1_id
join t3 c on a.id = c.t1_t2_id`

Answer (score -2):

I think this will work for you (number if t1 ids in t2):

```
SELECT count(*) from t1,t3 where t1.id=t2.t1_id;
```

Comment: you are using t2 in the where, when t2 is not part of your select?

Comment: also avoid using implicit joins, they are deprecated